# c++ error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ and ‘long int’)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, ros, catkin

I'm trying to catkin_make the github package from this link:

https://github.com/sontdhust/wandrian_src

However, it keeps returning this error:

> no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::basic_istream<char>' and 'long int')

I have traced the error to the below code, but I have no idea what is wrong as I'm new to C++.

```cpp
namespace wandrian {
namespace environment {
namespace boustrophedon {

ExtendedMap::ExtendedMap(RectanglePtr boundary, std::list<RectanglePtr> obstacles) : Map(boundary, obstacles) {}

ExtendedMap::ExtendedMap(std::string map_path) : Map(map_path) {}

ExtendedMap::~ExtendedMap() {}

void ExtendedMap::build() {
  std::string size;
  std::string position;
  std::string line;
  std::list<PointPtr> list_point_temp;
  PointPtr center, temp_point;
  double size_x, size_y;
  int i, flag;
  std::fstream read_file;
  std::size_t flag_start, flag_end;
  if (this->map_path.compare("") != 0) {
    read_file.open(this->map_path.c_str());
    if (read_file.is_open()) {
      int i = 1;
      int flag = 0;
      while (getline(read_file, line) != NULL) {
        flag = 0;
        position = "";
        size = "";
        flag_start = -1;
        while (line.find("(", flag_start + 1) < line.length()) {
          flag_start = line.find("(", flag_start + 1);
          flag_end = line.find(")", flag_start + 1);
          temp_point = create_point_to_string(line.substr(flag_start + 1, flag_end - flag_start - 1));
          list_point_temp.push_back(temp_point);
        }
        i = 0;
        for (std::list<PointPtr>::iterator u = list_point_temp.begin(); u != list_point_temp.end(); ++u) {
          if (i == 0) {
            size_y = (*u)->y;
          }
          if (i == 1) {
            size_x = (*u)->x;
            size_y = (*u)->y - size_y;
          }
          if (i == 2) {
            size_x = (*u)->x - size_x;
          }
          i++;
          if (i == 4) {
            std::cout << size_x << " " << size_y << std::endl;
            center = PointPtr(new Point((*u)->x - size_x / 2, (*u)->y + size_y / 2));
          }
        }

        if (!this->boundary) {
          this->boundary = RectanglePtr(new Rectangle(center, size_x, size_y));
        } else {
          this->obstacles.push_back(RectanglePtr(new Rectangle(center, size_x, size_y)));
        }
        list_point_temp.clear();
      }
    } else {
      std::cout << "Can't open file " << std::endl;
    }
    read_file.close();
  }
}

int ExtendedMap::comma_position(std::string str) {
  for (unsigned int position = 0; position < str.length(); ++position) {
    if (str[position] == ',')
      return position;
  }
  return 0;
}

PointPtr ExtendedMap::create_point_to_string(std::string str) {
  int flag;
  flag = str.find(",");
  return PointPtr(
      new Point(strtod(str.substr(0, flag).c_str(), NULL), strtod(str.substr(flag + 1, str.length()).c_str(), NULL)));
}
}
```

Comment: `while (getline(read_file, line) != NULL)` should be `while (getline(read_file, line))`. [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) returns stream it received as reference, it cannot be `NULL`.

Comment: Not much context to go on, but this line looks suspicious `while (getline(read_file, line) != NULL) {` I would rewrite that as `while (getline(read_file, line)) {`

Comment: *but I have no idea what is wrong as im new to C++.* -- C++ is not a language where you can simply learn by copying and pasting code you get from websites.  The error pointed out by @Yksisarvinen is a big example of why it is pointless to use C++ code code libraries unless you know C++ reasonably well.

Comment: thank you for the advice, really appreciate it. I am trying to implement this code for navigation planning of turtlebot on gazebo, and this is the first time I'm doing navigation so im trying to learn as it goes. Apologise for the lack of context, and I would definitely build on my foundation in C++ .

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```cpp
while (getline(read_file, line) != NULL) {
```

`std::getline()` returns a `std::istream&` reference to the `std::istream` object it was given as input.  `NULL` is defined as just an alias for integer `0`.  You can't compare a `std::istream` object to an `int` value, hence the compiler error.

The correct line would look like this instead:

```cpp
while (getline(read_file, line)) {
```

`std::istream` has a [conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) that can be used in some contexts where a `bool` is expected, such as in `if` statements, to determine whether the stream is in [a failure state](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail) or not.  The above statement is equivalent to:

```cpp
while (!getline(read_file, line).fail()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

On one of the lines you did:

```
int flag = 0;
```

Keep this in mind flag is an integer...
Next up you do:

```
flag = str.find(",");
```

First of all, your code makes zero sense to me, what are you doing?? Storing an "," inside an integer value?? Secondly chances are you did not write a function to assign an int to a character.